# Bypass DevicePolicyManager UI

Tags: android

Whenever I programmatically lock my screen the DevicePolicyManager get confirmation from me. Is there is any way to bypass this confirmation step.

Comment: Please explain what "get confirmation from me" means. For example, you might post a screenshot of what you are referring to. `lockNow()` does not itself display any UI, so long as the app itself is marked as a device administrator by the user in Settings.

Comment: I mean a screen which informs the user that the data will be erased and all the contacts in the phone will be deleted.

Comment: That is not "lock my screen". That is "wipe the device".

Comment: Confirmation is needed only once and that is to make your app DeviceAdmin once Activated you can directly wipe the device.